# A6 SIM module keeps resetting

Tags: stm32, gsm, sim

I'm using a SIM A6 module (Goouuu Tech A6, I believe it's the same) to send messages. The problem is, once I plug in a SIM card, it keeps resetting (the green led blinks and kind of interrupts after 3-4 sec, then starts again). Any ideas on what might be the problem? Is the module broken?
Any advice is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm powering it from a 5V 3A rated power supply.

This is the code I'm using(to send a SMS by pushing a button, I'm using multiple buffers just to see exactly the response of the module after each command):

````
  while(!ATisOK){
        sprintf(ATcommand,"AT\r\n");
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *)ATcommand,strlen(ATcommand),1000);
        HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1, buffer1, 30, 100);
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        if(strstr((char *)buffer1,"OK")){
            ATisOK = 1;
        }
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        //memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
  }
  sprintf(ATcommand,"AT+CPIN?\r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *)ATcommand,strlen(ATcommand),1000);
  HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1, buffer2, 60, 100);
  HAL_Delay(1000);

  sprintf(ATcommand,"AT+CSQ\r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *)ATcommand,strlen(ATcommand),1000);
  HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1, buffer3, 30, 100);
  HAL_Delay(1000);

  sprintf(ATcommand,"AT+CREG?=1\r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *)ATcommand,strlen(ATcommand),1000);
  HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1, buffer4, 30, 100);
  HAL_Delay(1000);




  //memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_8)){
          OK=1;
          sprintf(ATcommand,"AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *)ATcommand,strlen(ATcommand),1000);
          HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1, buffer5, 30, 100);
          HAL_Delay(1000);
      sprintf(ATcommand,"AT+CMGS=\"%s\"\r\n",mobileNumber);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *)ATcommand,strlen(ATcommand),1000);
      HAL_Delay(100);
      sprintf(ATcommand,"Hello World, STM32 started%c",0x1a);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *)ATcommand,strlen(ATcommand),1000);
      HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1, buffer6, 30, 100);
      //memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
      HAL_Delay(2000);
      }
      else {
          OK=0;
      }

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```
````

Comment: Please provide more informtion about your setup. Links to datasheets and product pages make it much easier for people to answer your question. Please also explain the steps you have taken already. Your setup and what you expect to get. Maybe also type of sim card and what your setup looks like.

Comment: Does the SIM work in a mobile phone? Does the SIM have an unlock code set? Have you read and followed the instructions on this page? https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=Crowtail-_A6_GPRS/GSM_Module

Comment: @kruemi Hi, the SIM works in a phone. I'm using a STM32F303RE board. I'm communicating with the GSM module through USART1. Will update the original post with the code I'm testing the module. Thanks for answering!!